# How to create draft in gmail api

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to create a new draft for a user with the gmail api, however i am getting an error I dont understand.

I searched but can't find a way to fix this error in gmail api, i know how to fix it please help

## error

> code: 403,
> errors: [
> {
> message: 'Insufficient Permission',
> domain: 'global',
> reason: 'insufficientPermissions'
> }
> ]

## my code

```
async function sendMessage() {
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client });
    var drafts = await gmail.users.drafts.create({
        userId: "me",
        requestBody: {
            id: "",
            message: {
                raw: "LS0tLQpGcm9tOiBKb2huIERvZSA8c0BnbWFpbC5jb20+ClRvOiBNYXJ5IFNtaXRoIDxzQGdtYWlsLmNvbT4KU3ViamVjdDogU2F5aW5nIEhlbGxvCkRhdGU6IEZyaSwgMjEgTm92IDE5OTcgMDk6NTU6MDYgLTA2MDAKTWVzc2FnZS1JRDogPDEyMzRAbG9jYWwubWFjaGluZS5leGFtcGxlPgoKaGVsbG8KLS0tLQ=="
            }
        }
    }).catch((v) => {
        console.log(v)
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> message: 'Insufficient Permission', domain: 'global', reason: 'insufficientPermissions'

Means that when you authorized this user you did not request enough scopes of authorization in order to use this method.

The [Quick start for node.js](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)
Has you use

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
```

While [users.drafts.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/create) requires one of the following scopes

[image]

Which means you need to change the scope in your code reauthorize your application which will request the proper scope from your user.

## tip

To remove authorization make sure to delete the file in token.json it contains the users access token and refresh token, once deleted it will request authorization of your application again

```
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
```